GCC optimizes x + n > y as x + (n-1) >= y?
In general, the program
extern int x, y;
int main() {
    return x + N > y;
}

is optimized into something akin to x + N-1 >= y for some given N. Example below. Am I reading the assembly right? If so, why does this happen? I thought > and >= were virtually identical in in terms of speed, and benchmarks (source) seem to agree?
E.x. for
extern int x, y;
int main() {
    return x + 50 > y;
}

the generated assembly is
main:
        mov     eax, DWORD PTR x[rip]
        add     eax, 49
        cmp     eax, DWORD PTR y[rip]
        setge   al
        movzx   eax, al
        ret

which seems to correspond with x + 49 >= y (on Godbolt)

It's probably not an optimization for execution speed, but for optimizations themselves. (That is, the compiler makes transforms that limit the number of instructions it uses, potentially simplifying future optimization passes.)

If you use unsigned x, y;, then you won't get this optimization, because the overflow behaviorsof + 49 and  + 50 is different.

It lessens the chance of integer overflow.

Another guess is that the compiler generates both versions and tests if one is better (which could happen in a case like x+1 > y). In this case, they're both equally good, so it might just choose one arbitrarily, and it just happens to be the one that looks less like the original code.

@WeatherVane for N not being constant expression it does not

Interestingly, in line with @WeatherVane’s comment – x - 50 compiles to sub eax, 50 with setg, and x - 50 >= y to sub eax, 49.

Also regarding @WeatherVane's comment, if there is arithmetic overflow, the result is implementation-defined (or an implementation-defined signal is raised, but most implementations do not do that), but shouldn't the implementatiion-defined value be representable in the common arithmetic type, which is int in this case? Consider an implementation where integers wrap around on overflow (which is pretty common), and suppose x is INT_MAX - 49 and y is INT_MAX. Then x + 50 would wrap around to INT_MIN so x + 50 > y would be false, but x + 49 >= y is true.

@IanAbbott: If there is overflow in an arithmetic operation with the int type, the behavior is not defined by the C standard. The C standard does not make it implementation-defined. (Conversion to int is implementation-defined when the value is out of int bounds.)

@EricPostpischil Conversion to int is implementation-defined when the value is out of int bounds, but whatever that value is ought to lie within the range of int. So how can the sum of two int values end up comparing greater than INT_MAX?

@EricPostpischil See https://godbolt.org/z/9GqdP8q6W Shouldn't all the comparisons be the same?

@IanAbbott: There is no conversion to int in your Compile Explorer examples. x, y, 50, n, and INT_MAX are all int, and all the + and > operations leave them as int. There is overflow; x + 50 and x + n overflow. When there is overflow, the C standard does not define the behavior, and there is no requirement that the results be the same.

@EricPostpischil On second thoughts, it is UB by the exceptional condition rule, so I agree there is no requirement that the results be the same. (Ref.: C17 6.5p5 "If an exceptional condition occurs during the evaluation of an expression (that is, if the result is not mathematically defined or not in the range of representable values for its type), the behavior is undefined.")
